# How long will Ultegra 11 speed mechanical parts (R8000) be available?

Tags: shimano

Given that the latest release of Shimano Ultegra (R8100) is 12 speed and electronic only, how long will it be before you can’t get Ultegra level replacement parts (not 105) for the Ultegra 11 speed mechanical group sets (R8000)?

Comment: Note that the Shimano supply issue is a unexpected one caused by COVID-19 supply chain disruptions (and probably the factory fire still). It’s not something Shimano planned to do.

Comment: @MaplePanda I'll take my second paragraph out of the question so that it isn't specific to the current strange circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Before you edited your question, you cited the Shimano Ultegra 6800 question. It should be pointed out that it isn't relevant as R8000 was a complete replacement and any worn or broken 6800 component can be replaced with an R8000 component for identical or improved functionality.

When going fully electronic and 12sp, the 11sp mechanical system is orphaned. Shimano usually keep high tier, end of generation service parts available for a long time (the Dura Ace octalink bottom bracket, Ultegra 9sp cassettes etc) so you can expect chain, cassette sprockets, maybe chainrings to be available for a long time. However, the derailleurs and shifters are likely to fall out of production within 5 years according to previous patterns. They may survive a bit longer but the slack is more likely to be taken up by the 105 components which will serve "legacy" 11sp riders for much longer with a more complete selection of replacement parts.

Of course, you will have to contact Shimano office for your region for a validated answer; their contact details are on their website.